# Electron preload javascript with persistence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to do some automation with my electron app as a proof of concept for a legacy application replacement for my company. I understand that we can't really interact with the DOM from the main window, so I am trying to see what approaches I can take here.

I created a `preload.js` file that is being injected into the window. This preload file essentially uses an `ipcRenderer` to listen and then when triggered, it sends data back to the parent.

This works fine, I am able to send data from the main.js to the process renderer and it returns data back to me.

```
// main.js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
})

mainWindow.loadURL('http://example.com');

// Listen for data from child
ipcMain.on('data-from-child', function (event, data) {
    console.log('From target', data)
});

// Send 
function sendData() {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('on-parent-recv', null);
}

// Send
sendData();
```

--

```
// preload.js
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
count = 0;

// Once we get something from the parent, send data back and then increment our counter
ipcRenderer.on('on-parent-recv', function (event, data) {
    ipcRenderer.send('data-from-child', { value: 'hello', count: count });
    count++;
});
```

The issue I am facing is when the user clicks on another link on example.com in the window we created, this injection I believe is re-injected? thus loses scope. As a test, I created an interval and then navigated to another page. When I got the data back, it was at `0` again.

**My question**

Is there a way to preload a file into the window itself which isn't refreshed or reloaded into the page each time?

If I was using `webview` for example, the renderer process would never change and the javascript file would remain on there while the `webview` would be changing allowing me to keep scope/state.

All I am trying to do here is automate the website I am loading within the `browserWindow` which is proving difficult. I am unable to use `nightmarejs` because the website uses NTLM to send the credentials and I don't think this is supported in that library.

Comment: this: _for a legacy application replacement for my company_ So curious how the _legacy app_ accomplishes this task.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - It uses IE ActiveX objects for all of the automation. This allows us to have `example.js` create a variable called `count=0`, create an ActiveX objects and do some automation on the website and then update `count++;`. It is more difficult to do with Electron with our main process not having access to manipulate the DOM. This is where I was trying to inject the payload so I could try and do some type of "control" with the website I am working with. So yeah, very legacy and I want to get away from it.

Comment: Webview sounds like a valid workaround indeed, which would simply decouple the event sniffer from the count scope... which you could already do by moving your count to the main process, while keeping your event sniffer in the renderer and just send a ping instead of a count.

Comment: @ghybs I agree that would probably work fine but I don't know for how long. It sounds like it could be removed in the near future? 

"Electron's webview tag is based on Chromium's webview, which is undergoing dramatic architectural changes. This impacts the stability of webviews, including rendering, navigation, and event routing. We currently recommend to not use the webview tag and to consider alternatives, like iframe, Electron's BrowserView, or an architecture that avoids embedded content altogether." https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag

Comment: I understand your reluctance from using a webview, so why not trying to achieve the same thing with main an renderer first? Its almost exactly the same setup.

Comment: Definitely go the webview route, or do your bookkeeping on another renderer process or maybe even a worker (if you can forgo electron native modules). Just do not do this on the main process unless you want to introduce performance issues.

Comment: I may be using the wrong tool for the job in this case, im not sure. End goal here is to be able to scrape and automate internal websites. Having done this in ActiveX (IE) for a while, I assumed this would be much better to do in Chromium but didn't think about the disconnect between reading and writing from the DOM. I will see what I can do with webview but it may still not even solve my problem.